# TypeError: cannot read property 'id' of undefined - Angular 8 Testing

Tags: javascript, angular, unit-testing

I am getting TypeError: cannot read property 'id' of undefined when trying to perform unit test in my angular 8 application.

Here is my template

```html
<h4>{{student.id}}</h4>
```

Here is my component

```js
import {Component, EventEmitter, Input, OnInit} from '@angular/core';
import { Student } from '@app/app-types';

@Component({
...... saved some typing
})

export class StudentComponent implements OnInit {
@Input() student: Student;
refreshForm: EventEmitter<any>;

constructor(){}

ngOnInit(){
  this.refreshForm = new EventEmitter();
  }
}
```

and here is the unit test

```js
import {async, ComponentFixture, TestBed } from '@angular/core/testing';
import {StudentComponet} from './student-component';

describe('StudentComponet', () => {
  let component: StudentComponent;
  let fixture: ComponentFixture<StudentComponent>;
  
  beforeEach(async(() => {
  TestBed.configureTestingModule({
    declarations: [StudentComponent]
  }).compileComponents();
  }));
  
  beforeEach(() => {
    fixture = TestBed.createComponent(StudentComponent);
    component = fixture.componentInstance;
    fixture.detectChanges();
  });
  
  it('should create', () => {
  expect(component).toBeTruthy();
  })
  
  });
```

Comment: Is student one time instanciated ?

Comment: @FrV Yes. The student is received from the  parent component via ngrx/store .

Answer (score 6, accepted):

use

```
student?.id
```

in unit test you have to provide value for student

```
beforeEach(() => {
  ...
  component.student = value;
  fixture.detectChanges();
);
```

Comment: Thank you for the reply. Can you please share how can I get that `component.student = value` dynamically, instead of hardcoding the value?

Comment: like value from backend?

Comment: Not really. What should I give the value in `component.student = value `? As the student imported in component is an interface.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32628864/anonymous-inline-interface-implementation-in-typescript here you have how to implements interfaces inline