# TypeScript 1.6 Ionic error TS2322 Build Type is not assignable to type 'IActionSheetOptions'

Tags: visual-studio, cordova, typescript, ionic-framework

I updated Visual Studio 2015 to TypeScript 1.6 and my Apache Cordova application broke. I'm getting errors with Ionic UIActionSheet Options cssClass.  For example, the line:

`cssClass: "class_action_sheet"`

results in the error: TS2322 Build Type is not assignable to type 'IActionSheetOptions'.

I tried to add a flag to the project file to suppress the new strictness, but either I added it wrong, or it can't be fixed that way.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is of the same type of problem addressed [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31816061/why-am-i-getting-an-error-object-literal-may-only-specify-known-properties).

This seems to be a reversal of 'type compatibility' premise, but discussing that won't solve the problem.

The easiest solution is to make sure your ionic.d.ts file is complete. There is [a version on definitely typed](https://github.com/borisyankov/DefinitelyTyped/tree/master/ionic) currently that does contain a property for cssClass in action sheet options, however it is not a direct descendant of the .d.ts file you are currently using and this will imply some refactoring.

For example the action sheet options is *ionic.actionSheet.IonicActionsheetOptions* **not** *Ionic.IActionSheetOptions*.

Another option would be to extend the interface on your own by saying interface MyActionSheetOptions extends Ionic.IActionSheetOptions, then define cssClass.

This seems incorrect to me as it's not a true subset but merely trying to fix gaps in the ionic definition file.