# How to declare TypeScript object interface that has exact fields and any extra properties

Tags: typescript

I do have some problems with declaration of Redux Action Type. By definition the Redux Action **should** have `type` property and **could** have some other properties.

According to TypeScript [interfaces page in HandBook](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/interfaces.html) (see "Excess Property Checks") i could do it like that:

```js
interface IReduxAction {
  type: string;
  [propName: string]: any;
}
```

And seems it work in some situations (like declaration of a variable)

```js
const action: IReduxAction = {
  type: 'hello',
  value: 'world'
};
```

But if i am trying to declare function that is using the action:

```js
function hello(state = {}, action: IReduxAction) {
  return { type: action.type, text: action.text };
}
```

It fails with the message "Property `text` does not exist on type `IReduxAction`".

What am i doing wrong? How to declare the general action type?

Live example on TypeScript playground is [here](http://www.typescriptlang.org/play/index.html#src=interface%20IReduxAction%20%7B%0D%0A%09type%3A%20string%3B%0D%0A%09%5BpropName%3A%20string%5D%3A%20any%3B%0D%0A%7D%0D%0A%0D%0Aconst%20action%3A%20IReduxAction%20%3D%20%7B%0D%0A%09type%3A%20'hello'%2C%0D%0A%09value%3A%20'world'%0D%0A%7D%3B%0D%0A%0D%0Afunction%20hello(state%20%3D%20%7B%7D%2C%20action%3A%20IReduxAction)%20%7B%0D%0A%09return%20%7B%20type%3A%20action.type%2C%20text%3A%20action.text%20%7D%3B%0D%0A%7D)

P.S. I checked "similar" questions, like [Why am I getting an error "Object literal may only specify known properties"?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31816061/why-am-i-getting-an-error-object-literal-may-only-specify-known-properties), and haven't found the solution there...

P.S.S. Apparently it **does** work in latest version of TypeScript.

Answer (score 2):

In that same page you referenced it talks about it in the section titled `Indexable Types`.

You'll need to do this:

```
function hello(state = {}, action: IReduxAction) {
    return { type: action.type, text: action["text"] };
}
```

As your interface definition is defined to have index from string (key) to any (value).

Comment: I read that section as well. And with your changes it works fine. The problem is - i don't want to use non-dot notation here. Its normal JavaScript notation and it should be possible to make it work somehow... The question is - how?

Comment: As far as I know you can't, that's how typescript differentiate between known fields and indexable ones.