# TS: why can assign not valid type to generic type variable?

Tags: generics, typescript

Not sure how how to fomulate the question, but this is the case:

```
interface X {
  some: number
}

let arr1: Array<X> = Array.from([{ some: 1, another: 2 }]) // no error
let arr2: Array<X> = Array.from<X>([{ some: 1, another: 2 }]) // will error
```

([code in playground](http://www.typescriptlang.org/play/index.html#src=interface%20X%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20some%3A%20number%0D%0A%7D%0D%0A%0D%0Alet%20arr1%3A%20Array%3CX%3E%20%3D%20Array.from(%5B%7B%20some%3A%201%2C%20another%3A%202%20%7D%5D)%20%2F%2F%20no%20error%0D%0Alet%20arr2%3A%20Array%3CX%3E%20%3D%20Array.from%3CX%3E(%5B%7B%20some%3A%201%2C%20another%3A%202%20%7D%5D)%20%2F%2F%20will%20error))

The error:

```
Argument of type '{ some: number; another: number; }[]' is not assignable to parameter of type 'ArrayLike<X>'.
  Index signatures are incompatible.
    Type '{ some: number; another: number; }' is not assignable to type 'X'.
      Object literal may only specify known properties, and 'another' does not exist in type 'X'.
```

Why in first case there is no error (no type comparability check), is it by design or there is an issue for this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's look at the types of the two array instances.
If we take away the type definitions:

```
// type of arr1 is { some: number; another: number; }[]
let arr1 = Array.from([{ some: 1, another: 2 }]);

// type of arr2 is X[]
let arr2 = Array.from<X>([{ some: 1, another: 2 }]);
```

([code in playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#src=interface%20X%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20some%3A%20number%0A%7D%0A%0Alet%20arr1%20%3D%20Array.from(%5B%7B%20some%3A%201%2C%20another%3A%202%20%7D%5D)%3B%0Alet%20arr2%20%3D%20Array.from%3CX%3E(%5B%7B%20some%3A%201%2C%20another%3A%202%20%7D%5D)%3B): hover the array variables to see the types)

This is because the signature for [Array.from](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/blob/master/lib/lib.es6.d.ts#L4219) is:

```
from<T>(arrayLike: ArrayLike<T>): Array<T>;
```

The compiler doesn't complain for `arr1` because it infers the generic constraint based on the value that is passed to the function.
But in the case of `arr2` the generic constraint is set to `X`, and the type `{ some: number; another: number; }` doesn't match it.

If you'll try to add an `X` to `arr1`:

```
arr1.push({ some: 3 });
```

You'll get:

```
Argument of type '{ some: number; }' is not assignable to parameter of type '{ some: number; another: number; }'.
  Property 'another' is missing in type '{ some: number; }'.
```

Answer (score 1):

Very very interesting, I didn't know that.

It looks like any strongly-typed array literals can only contain **known** elements.
From the error message, it is looking like it is by design rather than a bug.

Comment: This restriction is not limited to arrays, and is explained in great detail in [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/31816062/43848)