# TypeScript: Discriminated Unions with optional values

Tags: typescript

Given the following types:

```
interface FullName {
  fullName?: string
}

interface Name {
  firstName: string
  lastName: string
}

type Person = FullName | Name;

const p1: Person = {};
const p2: Person = { fullName: 'test' };
const p3: Person = { firstName: 'test' }; // Does not throw
const p4: Person = { badProp: true }; // Does throw, as badProp is not on FullName | Name;
```

I would expect `p3` to result in a compiler error, as `firstName` is present without `lastName`, but it doesn't -- is this a bug or expected?

Additionally, making FullName.fullName required results in `p3` (and `p1`) causing errors.

Comment: Probably a separate question, but is there a way to enforce an optional union? That is, say `FullName` did require `fullName`. Is there a way to enforce `Person` requiring (`fullName`) OR (`firstName` and `lastName`) OR neither?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The type in your question is not, in usual sense, discriminated union - your union members don't have common, non-optional literal property called [discriminant](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/advanced-types.html#discriminated-unions).

So, as @Alex noted in his answer, your union is somewhat similar to

```
type Person = {
  fullName?: string
  firstName?: string
  lastName?: string
}
```

so it can be initialized with `{ firstName: 'test' }`

With true discriminated unions, you get back the logic for checking non-optional properties, as well as checking that object literal may only specify known properties:

```
interface FullName {
  kind: 'fullname';  
  fullName?: string
}

interface Name {
  kind: 'name';  
  firstName: string
  lastName: string
}

type Person = FullName | Name;

const p1: Person = {kind: 'fullname'};  // ok
const p2: Person = {kind: 'fullname', fullName: 'test' };  // ok
```

checking non-optional property:

```
const p3: Person = {kind: 'name', firstName: 'test' };
```

error:

```
Type '{ kind: "name"; firstName: string; }' is not assignable to type 'Person'.
  Type '{ kind: "name"; firstName: string; }' is not assignable to type 'Name'.
    Property 'lastName' is missing in type '{ kind: "name"; firstName: string; }'.
```

checking extra property:

```
const p5: Person = { kind: 'fullname', bar: 42 }
```

error:

```
Type '{ kind: "fullname"; bar: number; }' is not assignable to type 'Person'.
  Object literal may only specify known properties, and 'bar' does not exist in type 'Person'.
```

**However**, as @JeffMercado found out, type checking is still a bit off:

```
const p6: Person = { kind: 'fullname', firstName: 42 };  // no error. why?
```

I'd consider posting an issue for typescript github project.

Comment: Oddly enough, this also doesn't report errors with the original: `const p5: Person = { firstName: 42 };`

Comment: I think I know why. You aren't actually taking advantage of the discriminated union pattern here. `kind` is just like a propertly like all the rest, but they have different types (string literal types) in both FullName and Name. p3 don't work because it's not compatible with neither of the constituents. p5 does not work because bar is not a known property of any of the constituents. However, p6 is fine because it's compatible with `FullName` and `firstName` is a known property of one of the constituents.

Comment: To actually "activate" the discriminated union, you have to type guard it like they do in the part of the documentation you linked to. It's first then TS will narrow the type accordingly.

Answer (score 6):

First of, your interface `FullName` does only contain one optional property, that is basically making it match anything. Then when you do a union type with it, the resulting type is going to be compatible with everything.

**However**, there is another concern considering declaring and assigning literal objects, and that is that you only can declare known properties: [Why am I getting an error "Object literal may only specify known properties"?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/31816061/681538)

So you could do this without any problem:

```
var test = { otherStuff: 23 };
const p4: Person = test;
```

But not this

```
const p4: Person = { otherStuff: 23 };
```

And in your case `firstName` is a known property of `FullName | Name`, so it's all ok.

And as @artem answered, `discriminated unions` have a special meaning in typescript, apart from regular unions, requiring special structural assumptions.

Comment: I could be wrong, but it doesn't seem like an interface with an optional property results in the type being equivalent to `any`. For example, if that were the case setting `const p4: Person = { badProp: true }` would not cause an error?

Comment: @BenSouthgate No, it's not totally equivalent with any, bad wording on my part.

Comment: @BenSouthgate And to extend on that: All objects match the empty type {}, just like they would match a type with only one optional property. However, declaring a object literal is another question. Here we have another constraint, and that is that we can only declare properties that matches the type the declared object is being assigned to. It does **not** mean that the object does not actually fulfill the target type.

Comment: And a type with an single optional property is not equivalent with `any` because `any` can be seen to have all possible properties that an object can have, each being optional. So if your union type would contain a `any`, all properties would be allowed to declare in the object literal targeting that union type. That is not the case for the type with the lone optional property. Although, they do seem to disregard from the rule about  only declaring known properties if one of the constituents are completely empty. like `{}|Name`.

Answer (score 0):

**2021 Update**: The example in the question now works as intended.

Since at least TypeScript version `3.3.3` (the oldest version one can currently test on the TypeScript playground) you don't need a discriminant (i.e. a common, non-optional literal property).

Given

```
interface FullName {
  fullName?: string
}

interface Name {
  firstName: string
  lastName: string
}

type Person = FullName | Name;
```

as in the question, the following example (marked as "Does not throw" by the person asking this question)

```
const p3: Person = { firstName: 'test' }; // Does not throw
```

now leads to this TypeScript error:

```
Property 'lastName' is missing in type '{ firstName: string; }' but required in type 'Name'.
```

---

And @artem was wondering why

```
const p6: Person = { kind: 'fullname', firstName: 42 };
```

would not throw an error in his example with the discriminant `kind`.

Well, since at last TypeScript version 3.3.3 it does throw an error, precisely the expected one:

```
Object literal may only specify known properties, and 'firstName' does not exist in type 'FullName'.
```

See [this TypeScript playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ts=3.3.3#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-19ioZwdqsYjsd1JHzACiAA82M56FRcKQ6fh2qQ5eJ6IhpJtcPRHJA7qRnLieDtWJA77hnGJhHMJAoOlkAAN1Jeg9gAOmiVhgAAR1eCQUGyYBjniY4AE52yaScMOAU0BgxRBXwAWludFMWxXESNoAlshI3ZEC2EjQVwZDSHoEiQI4xDBAvMRdiIY8rh8Cg2LAgBiYSSNwUFwCAA) which includes both examples (with and without discriminated union).