# Cannot set width of fancybox

Tags: javascript, jquery, typescript, fancybox

I have Typescript code, where I need to set width of fancy box

Here is script code

```
 export module Step2{
    export function loading(){
    Tabs.customCheckbox("conditions");
    Tabs.customCheckbox("newsletter");
    $('select.custom1').selectmenu();

    LoadActions.load_passenger_datepickers();
    LoadActions.load_field_actions();
    LoadActions.load_button_actions();
    LoadActions.load_form_actions();
    $('.fancybox').fancybox();
    $('.fancyconditions').fancybox({ width: '60%', height: '60%', baseClass: 'fancyconditions' });
    $('.tip').tooltipster({ contentAsHTML: true });

    $('.bonuscard_info').toggle();
    if (gon && gon.search['id']) { CheckStatus.check_status(); }

    if (localStorage.getItem('rescheduled_flight') === '1') {
      localStorage.removeItem('rescheduled_flight');
      Track.log_event("Show rescheduled flight");
      return $.fancybox.open($('#step_2_rescheduled'));
    }
    }
};
```

But here `$('.fancyconditions').fancybox({ width: '60%', height: '60%', baseClass: 'fancyconditions' });`

I get error

> Argument of type '{ width: string; height: string; baseClass: string; }' is not assignable to parameter of type 'any[]'.
>     Object literal may only specify known properties, and 'width' does not exist in type 'any[]'.

How I can solve it?

Comment: have you seen this question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31816061/why-am-i-getting-an-error-object-literal-may-only-specify-known-properties?

Comment: But I have it in 'index.d.ts' of fancybox @ShyamBabu

Comment: I'm quite sure that issue is with your `'index.d.ts' of fancybox` - where did you get that file anyway?

Comment: Can you check if the typings are getting loaded properly?