# How to check if an object contains just the specified keys in Typescript?

Tags: typescript

Let's see we have an union of strings:

```
type PossibleKeys = 'foo' | 'bar'
```

And we want a type which checks if an object contains no other keys than the above:

```
type ValidObject = { [key in PossibleKeys]: any }
```

This works, but it accepts other keys as well, and it requires all the keys, which can be solved with marking it as optional `?`, but still accepts other keys.

What I want is to accept:

```
{foo: true, bar: true}
{foo: true}
{bar: true}
{}
```

And do not accept:

```
{foo: true, bar: true, baz: true}
```

Basically anything else which is not in the accept example.

Is that possible?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is essentially a duplicate of [another](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56606614/is-there-an-alternative-to-partial-to-accept-only-fields-from-another-type-and-n) question.  Translating the answer there to this question gives the following solution:

```
type PossibleKeys = 'foo' | 'bar'
type Exactly<T, U> = T & Record<Exclude<keyof U, keyof T>, never>;
const asValidObject =
    <T extends Exactly<Partial<Record<PossibleKeys, any>>, T>>(t: T) => t;

const a = asValidObject({ foo: true, bar: true }); // okay
const b = asValidObject({ foo: true }); // okay
const c = asValidObject({ bar: true }); // okay
const d = asValidObject({}); // okay
const e = asValidObject({ foo: true, bar: true, baz: true }); // error!
// -------------------------------------------> ~~~
// true is not assignable to never
```

[Link to code](http://www.typescriptlang.org/play//#code/C4TwDgpgBACg9gZwQSwEYBsIGkIgVAXigHIAzOOYqAHxNQEMAnYgWAChRIoBRAD3oDGwdCAA8AFQA0UAKoA+QlHFQAZFABKEAXEYATUXwHoArroiiA1rjilZ0qyBtK50gHYQAbhEZyA3O21XBGAoegQANXp0ZF0AeVQAKy0QgnYodKgJKAheYAhXXXw+QWExGCZgZCjRTW09UXgkNEwcPGl6VxA5F2c5AApgAC4lAEpCBWB-NgC4IJD6RTDI6LjE5L6AbyhyOGHgRmMIaQZGPYPoAF8R3ygAeluoOAt6EBm5qFRFiKiY+KShTbbChnQ5QK43e6PZ6vNiBYJQARfZa-NYArYnEGXa53B5PF5veG6JE-Vb-YCbcE4qH42GzeHQIhLEl-dZbHaY45MDkfegAL0xYOxkO8jB0AEJ2JCALQy2Vy+UKxVKxUKAB+6slD32oOQ+FccHmTQA5q56BhoMA4FB3F5GOx2EA)

Hope that helps; good luck!