# typescript doesn't throw typeerror on an array push of wrong type

Tags: arrays, typescript

The following code does not transpile, as I would expect.

```
interface Interface1 {
    a: number;
    b: number;
}

const arr: Array<Interface1> = []

arr.push({
    a: 1,
    b: 1,
    c: 1
})
```

However, as soon as I turn the pushed object into an interface (not matching interface 1), the code successfully transpiles.

```
interface Interface2 {
    a: number;
    b: number;
    c: number;
}

const test: Interface2 = {
    a: 1,
    b: 1,
    c: 1
}

arr.push(test)
```

What is going on, and how can I successfully throw a typeError upon this incorrect array push?

Reproduction link: https://codesandbox.io/s/flamboyant-knuth-8lq82?file=/src/index.ts

Comment: This is called [excess property checks](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/interfaces.html#excess-property-checks) and it works exactly this way.  "Fresh" object literals are checked for extra properties.  "Non-fresh" object literals (ones that have been assigned to variables) are not.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is there an alternative to Partial to accept only fields from another type and nothing else?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56606614/is-there-an-alternative-to-partial-to-accept-only-fields-from-another-type-and-n)