# Why does TS treat anonymous object differently then declared objects?

Tags: typescript, typescript4.0, typescript3.8

Somewhere in our code there was an extra property that shouldn't be there and I realized it was the result of a recent refactor.
we refactored

```
foo({prop1: 1})
```

to

```
const props = {prop1: 1};
foo(props)
```

unfortunately somewhere along the way `prop2` was added.
pre-refactor this would error but post refactor there is no error

```
foo({prop1: 1, prop2: 1}) // Object literal may only specify known properties

const props = {prop1: 1, prop2: 1};
foo(props) // all good!?
```

Why does ts treat these two differently?
I even tried

```
const props = {prop1: 1, prop2: 1} as const;
foo(props) // all good
food({...props}) // still all good
```

Here is a simplified example along with the things I tested

```
type OKType = {good: string}
interface OKInterface {good: string}

const test = (obj: {good: string}) => true;
const test1 = (obj: OKType) => true;
const test2 = (obj: OKInterface) => true;

// awsome
test({
    good: 'a',
    bad: 'a',
}) //error
test1({
    good: 'a',
    bad: 'a',
}) //error
test2({
    good: 'a',
    bad: 'a',
}) //error

// wtf
const a = {
    good: 'a',
    bad: 'a',
}
test(a) //good
test1(a) //good
test2(a) //good
```

[ts-playground-link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBA8g0gFXNAvFA3gcwPbYCYBcUAzsAE4CWAdpgL4BQ1wEZAZgIYDG08AklczZdoWXIRLlqdevU7YqpKM0VoAFNgBGAKyKj8RUpRq0AlFBQA%20JWQCuEANyz5i5cACM5qOu1F4SSGaW1naOcgrAShCkAEye3jqwcPyCHNyBVuQhMgD02VDsAO7E2AC2EPSuquj0ULVQOPpQAOTsTQA0NXUa7OIt7fSmFVHuVZ21Db2tHXVQ3ZP9g67RozMTRH3TXT3rUwMmOXkFwKxO4fme1atiO-0zczcdDJXs%2065uqi9DMR-7QA)

is it possible to get the same type checking when passing a declared object into functions?

Seems like this has been answered here: [Forcing excess-property checking on variable passed to TypeScript function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54775790/forcing-excess-property-checking-on-variable-passed-to-typescript-function)

Comment: It's called [excess property checks](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/interfaces.html#excess-property-checks) - documented behaviour by design.

Comment: [Forcing excess-property checking on variable passed to TypeScript function](https://stackoverflow.com/q/54775790) | [Typescript: prevent assignment of object with more properties than is specified in target interface](https://stackoverflow.com/q/57497299) | [Is there an alternative to Partial to accept only fields from another type and nothing else?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/56606614) | [Typescript: prevent assignment of object with more properties than is specified in target interface](https://stackoverflow.com/q/57497299)