# Typescript - Constrain generic type based on the keys of another type

Tags: typescript

I'm attempting to write a typescript helper library to strongly type `process.env` so you can do the following. The library with throw if the variable is missing or can't be converted to the correct type.

```js
import { getEnv, num, str } from '@lib/env'

const env = getEnv({
  TABLE_NAME: num(),
})

// typeof env is
// const env: Readonly<{
//     TABLE_NAME: number;
// }>
```

I currently have the following code which works

```js
type Validator<T> = (
  defaultValue?: T,
) => (processEnvKey: string, processEnvValue?: string) => T

type Validators<T> = { [K in keyof T]: ReturnType<Validator<T[K]>> }

export const str: Validator<string> = (defaultValue) => (
  processEnvKey,
  processEnvValue,
) => {
  if (processEnvValue != null) return processEnvValue
  if (defaultValue != null) return defaultValue

  throw new Error(
    `Environment variable '${processEnvKey}' is required and no default was provided`,
  )
}

export const num: Validator<number> = (defaultValue) => (
  processEnvKey,
  processEnvValue,
) => {
  if (processEnvValue != null) {
    const processEnvValueAsNumber = Number(processEnvValue)
    if (Number.isNaN(processEnvValueAsNumber)) {
      throw new Error(
        `Environment variable '${processEnvKey}' is required to be numeric but could not parse '${processEnvValue}' as a number`,
      )
    }

    return processEnvValueAsNumber
  }

  if (defaultValue != null) return defaultValue

  throw new Error(
    `Environment variable '${processEnvKey}' is required and no default was provided`,
  )
}

export const getEnv = <T>(
  validators: Validators<T>,
  environment = process.env,
): Readonly<T> => {
  const result: Partial<T> = {}

  for (const processEnvKey in validators) {
    const validator = validators[processEnvKey]
    result[processEnvKey] = validator(processEnvKey, environment[processEnvKey])
  }

  return result as Readonly<T>
}
```

I now have a new requirement where I know in advance all the environment keys that are available as an interface

```js
interface Env {
  API_ENDPOINT: any
  TABLE_NAME: any
}
```

So I'm trying the change `getEnv` so that the object passed in can only contain the keys found in `Env`.

I tried changing `getEnv` but I'm getting stuck

```js
export const getEnv = <T extends { [K in keyof Env]?: ????>(
```

If I change it to

```js
export const getEnv = <T extends { [K in keyof Env]?: unknown>(
```

I can pass additional keys without the compiler complaining. The following doesn't cause a compiler error even though `NON_EXISTING_KEY` is not a key of `Env`

```js
const env = getEnv({
  TABLE_NAME: num(),
  NON_EXISTING_KEY: str(),
})
```

Comment: Try removing the generic `T` from `getEnv` and replace `T` with `Env` elsewhere in the function.

Comment: If you want to allow `T` to be a subtype of `Env`, then replace `????` in your question with `T[K]`.

Comment: If you don't care type of values then replace ```????``` with ```any```.  Thus ```T``` will be constraint only to specific keys.

Comment: Dont use `any`, use `unknown` please.

Comment: For this usecase you can use a battle tested yup library that allows you to define validation schema and can infer TypeScript types for free with 
`type Config = yup.InferType<typeof config>`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Nice idea!

This behavior is due to the way [generic constraints](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/generics.html#generic-constraints) are designed.
The constraint `T extends { [K in keyof Env]?: unknown }` enforces the *minimum requirements* for `T`. Naturally, any additional properties are allowed.

What you need is a proper [exact type](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/12936), which would prevent any excess properties from being defined.
User **jcalz** has a [really great answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56620917/8820824) that walks through one of these:

> ```js
> type Exactly<T, U> = T & Record<Exclude<keyof U, keyof T>, never>;
> ```
>
> This takes a type `T` and a *candidate* type `U` that we want to ensure is "exactly `T`". It returns a new type which is like `T` but with extra `never`-valued properties corresponding to the extra properties in `U`. If we use this as a constraint on `U`, like `U` extends `Exactly<T, U>`, then we can guarantee that `U` matches `T` and has no extra properties.

---

With this type available, you can declare your `getEnv` as follows:

```
export const getEnv = <T extends Exactly<{ [K in keyof Env]?: unknown }, T>>(
  validators: Validators<T>,
  environment = process.env,
): Readonly<T> => {};
```

Thus, `T` now *must* only match keys in `{ [K in keyof Env]?: unknown }` and you have the restriction you desire.

[Stackblitz reproduction.](https://stackblitz.com/edit/so-constrain-generic?devtoolsheight=33&file=index.ts)

---

**PS:** Due to the way `Validators` is defined, there is an edge-case where a property of type `() => never` can bypass the constraint. Now, I can't think of a reason someone would do this, but you can block this by updating the definition of `Validators`:

```
// from
type Validators<T> = { [K in keyof T]: ReturnType<Validator<T[K]>> }
// to
type Validators<T> = { [K in keyof T]: T[K] extends never ? never : ReturnType<Validator<T[K]>> };
```

The Stackblitz demonstrates this if you switch comments on line 17/18 and refresh.