# Typescript: why not strict return type?

Tags: typescript

There is a snipet with no error in return of funciton with decared return type.

```
type Human = {
  head: number
  body: number
}

const human: Human = {
  head: 1,
  body: 1,
}

const humanFn: (human: Human) => Human = (human) => {
  return {
    // ...human, 
    head: human.head,
    body: human.body,
    tail: 1, // allows illegal props
  }
}

humanFn({
  ...human,
  tail: 1, // here is and error
})
```

So the question is why TS allows adding additinal props to return object `tail: 1, // allows illegal props`? Is there a way to avoid it?

UPD:

so actually I found the exiting TS issue https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/241

And "workaround" to wrap return object in something like `R.identity<Human>(...)` (from ramda)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your code does not throw a compile error,
but the following code throws a compile error.

```
function humanFn(human: Human): Human {
  return {
    // ...human, 
    head: human.head,
    body: human.body,
    tail: 1, // Error
  }
}
```

and the following also does throw a compile error

```
const humanFn: (human: Human) => Human = (human): Human => {
  return {
    // ...human, 
    head: human.head,
    body: human.body,
    tail: 1, // Error
  }
}
```

Your question seems to be another case of [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57214325/typescript-excess-properties-are-not-checked-in-lambdas-without-explicit-return).

> Finally I found [the issue](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/7547) in GitHub, exactly about the problem. In
> short:
>
> > Ideally this would be an error. Unfortunately it turns out to be very
> > difficult to fix this without possibly having consequences in terms of
> > runaway recursion and/or performance

Comment: Ah, yes thanks didn't think about explictly putting return type, as workaround better then wrapping return result.