# React useState not being strict on type

Tags: reactjs, typescript, types, react-hooks

The following TypeScript type:

```
type Errors = ({
  err1: false;
} | {
  err1: true;
  msg1: string;
}) & ({
  err2: false;
} | {
  err2: true;
  msg2: string;
})
```

Which is basically a intersection of two discriminated unions, works as expected in plain TypeScript:

```
const customError: Errors = {
  err1: false,
  err2: false,
  attributeThatShouldntBeAllowed: 1 // It gives an IDE error
}
```

However, when it comes to React, particularly with useState hook:

```
const [errors, setErrors] = useState<Errors>({
  err1: false,
  err2: false
}) // proper initialization with Errors type, nothing wrong here
```

It becomes not a little bit strict about the type:

```
setErrors(prevState => ({
  ...prevState,
  attributeThatShouldntBeAllowed: "lol",
  anotherAttribute: 1
})) // Doesn't produce any errors
```

What exactly happens here?

As described, I had this issue in my current project and I've just created a basic sandbox. This is it's `tsconfig.json`:

```json
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "target": "es2016",
    "module": "commonjs",
    "esModuleInterop": true,
    "forceConsistentCasingInFileNames": true,
    "strict": true,
    "skipLibCheck": true
  }
}
```

Also, here it is the `tsconfig.json` of my current project:

```json
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "target": "es5",
    "module": "commonjs",
    "strict": true,
    "jsx": "react",
    "allowSyntheticDefaultImports": true,
    "baseUrl": ".",
    "paths": {
      "@domain/*": ["./src/domain/*"],
      "@infra/*": ["./src/infra/*"],
      "@types/*": ["./src/types/*"],
      "@controllers/*": ["./src/controllers/*"]
    }
  },
  "include": ["src", "node_modules"],
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You may simplify your type. Try this:

```
type Errors = {
  err1?: boolean;
  err2?: boolean 
  msg1?: string;
  msg2?: string 
}
```

As per your setState:

```
setErrors(prevState => ({
  ...prevState,
  youNeverUpdatedErrors,
  attributeThatShouldntBeAllowed: "lol",
  anotherAttribute: 1
}))
```

Comment: I like the type I used because it automatically gives me autocomplete, like, when I determine prop "err1" is true it automatically must have prop "msg1" and starts complaining. I very often use typescript types this way, constraining properties to each other and using discriminated unions. Do you think that is a bad practice?

Comment: You can get the autocomplete suggestions by pressing Option + Space on MacOS.

Comment: I personally wouldn’t use this Error type. The error type itself shouldn’t worry about the number of errors; only focus on the error message and body. Multiple errors may be better suited in a type that manages multiple errors. If no message present, you know there is no error

Answer (score 0):

Apparently, it is a normal behaviour of the structural type in TypeScript, that, considering a generic object type T, an object that has every attribute of T and any aditional attributes is assignable to T. If I explicitly determine the return function of setState, like this:

```
setErrors((state): Errors => ({
  ...state,
  attributeThatShouldntBeAllowed: "lol", // Now it produces an error
  anotherAttribute: 1
}))
```

it works as expected.

[TypeScript type compatibility](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/type-compatibility.html)

[Don't widen return types of function expressions #241](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/241)

[Typescript: why not strict return type?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63006497/typescript-why-not-strict-return-type)