# How do I resolve Object literal may only specify known properties, and 'xxxx' does not exist in type 'Partial<Object>'. in ModalOptions

Tags: angular, typescript, ngx-bootstrap, angular11, ngx-bootstrap-modal

## Background

Basically I had created a mixin for opening and closing my modals in `ngx-bootstrap/modal`

Below is the code for the modal

**modalMixin.ts**

```typescript
export const modalMixin = <T extends Constructor>(BaseClass: T = class {
} as T) =>
  class extends BaseClass {
    config: ModalOptions = {
      initialState: {id: 0},                // Problem is occurring here
      backdrop: true,
      ignoreBackdropClick: true,
      animated: true,
    };
    modalRef: BsModalRef;
    modalServiceInjected: BsModalService;
    constructor(...args: any[]) {
      super(...args);
      this.modalServiceInjected = args[0];
    }

    openModal({id, component}: { id: number; component: any; }) {
      this.storeInjected.dispatch(loadModals());
      this.config.initialState = {id};
      this.modalRef = this.modalServiceInjected.show(component, this.config);
      this.modalRef.setClass('modal-lg bg-dark text-light modal-container ');
    }

    closeModal() {
      // Some code here to dispatch action to close modal
    }
  };
```

Simply what I have achieved is that any class that extends my `modalMixin()` function has all required properties and function to open and close a modal. If I call `this.openModal({id: 123, component: SomeCompenent})` then `SomeComponent` will be opened with `@Input = 123` `123` being the value passed in the `openModal` function.

## Challenge

The above functionality is working only that I receive below error

```
Error: src/app/mixins/modal.mixin.ts:13:22 - error TS2322: Type '{ id: number; }' is not assignable to type 'Partial<Object>'.
  Object literal may only specify known properties, and 'id' does not exist in type 'Partial<Object>'.

13       initialState: {id: 0},
```

I do understand what the error is saying. As stated in this question  [Why am I getting an error "Object literal may only specify known properties"?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31816061/why-am-i-getting-an-error-object-literal-may-only-specify-known-properties), I understand that properties not included in the type will throw an error

but how do I pass `{ id: number }` as a `Partial<Object>`? Simply what properties are included in `Partial<Object>`

## WorkAround

Currently I have found two ways to make the error go away

```typescript
config: ModalOptions = {
      initialState: {id: 0} as Partial<Object>,
      backdrop: true,
      ignoreBackdropClick: true,
      animated: true,
    };
```

And simply

```typescript
config: any = {
      initialState: {id: 0} as Partial<Object>,
      backdrop: true,
      ignoreBackdropClick: true,
      animated: true,
    };
```

The above approaches seem to solve the problem, what I need now is how would I create an Object of the form `Partial<Object>`?