# initialState does not work anymore after update to ngx-bootrap 6.1.0

Tags: ngx-bootstrap, ngx-bootstrap-modal

We used the initialState from ModalOptions like this:

```
var modalConfig: ModalOptions = {
  initialState: {
    companyIdInput: this.companyId
  }
};
this.modalRef = this.modalService.show(AddEditCompanyModalComponent, modalConfig);
```

companyIdInput/this.companyId is a string.

Now, this does not work anymore. We have the following error:

**Type '{ companyIdInput: string; }' is not assignable to type 'Partial'.**

How we have to pass the values?

Thanks very much.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66046505/how-do-i-resolve-object-literal-may-only-specify-known-properties-and-xxxx-do