# Why does TypeScript break when passing args but not an object?

Tags: typescript

```js
type User = {
  firstName: string

}
const foo = (u: User) => null
const someUser = {
  firstName: "first",
  lastName: "last",
}
foo(someUser) // passes
foo({  // breaks
    firstName: "first",
    lastName: "last"
})
```

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBAqgzhATlAvFA3gKClAZgS0TmADkBDAWwgC4pjF8A7Ac00wF9MBjAe0eLw8eqKAAoArrXhIAlKgB8URuIA2K7nwFweVacjRYcBIqUo0oAImPELAGmxQVZYuSq0LTm-c64ho7boIiDKYvjyihjh4hC5m7tbAdg44nqZulqkWHDJAA)

Why does typescript break when calling the function with explicit args:

```
Argument of type '{ firstName: string; lastName: string; }' is not assignable to parameter of type 'User'.
  Object literal may only specify known properties, and 'lastName' does not exist in type 'User'.(2345)
```

but not when passing an object?

Comment: Because when you inline the object literal you get _excess property checks_. If you typed the `user` variable you'd get the same thing.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Why am I getting an error "Object literal may only specify known properties"?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31816061/why-am-i-getting-an-error-object-literal-may-only-specify-known-properties)

Answer (score 0):

From [the manual](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/interfaces.html#excess-property-checks):

> You could argue that this program is correctly typed, since the width
> properties are compatible, there’s no color property present, and the
> extra colour property is insignificant.
>
> However, TypeScript takes the stance that there’s probably a bug in
> this code. Object literals get special treatment and undergo excess
> property checking when assigning them to other variables, or passing
> them as arguments. If an object literal has any properties that the
> “target type” doesn’t have, you’ll get an error: